# Get only the last day and the day before data from API call for comparison

Tags: javascript, angular

I made an API call in a service. ts that gives me all the data from 01/01/21 till now (01/06/21) but I want to show in my table only the data of last day, Is there any way to do this?

- All the data is already arranged by date from the oldest to the newest.
  Thank you!

For example, This is my interface :

```
export interface SaleByCustomer {
    account_id: number;
    doctype: number;
    owner?: number;
    company: string;
    issue_date: Date;
    total: number;
    currency_id?: string;
}
```

Because of information security I can't show the data, but I have for each `issua_date` several records and I want to get in my component.ts only the data for the last day and the day before for comparison.

This is what I've tried in my Service.ts : (I got nothing in my console)

```
getSale() {
    let json = {
      "login_id": "xxxxxxxx",
      "login_hash": "xxxxxxx",
      "login_company": "xx",
      "query": {"doctype":[x], "refstatus":[0,1], "issue_date":"2021-05-01 to 2021-05-31"}
    }
    let body = JSON.stringify(json); //text to input in internet
    let today = new Date();
    let yesterday = new Date();
    yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.URL, body).pipe(
      filter(a => a.issue_date >= yesterday && a.issue_date < today)
    );
  }
```

Component.ts :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.saleCompareService.getSale().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
  }
```

After I get All the data from those 2 days, I want to compare them in a bar chart, what's the best way?

Comment: Filter out unneeded records. To get proper answer you need to put some effort in question. Provide sample of data at least. And it’s not related to angular, it’s a JavaScript/typescript question

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok sorry, I'm kind of new, I added my interface sample of what I get.

Comment: This is not a TypeScript specific question is is probably just a matter of using a `.filter` method. Have you tried anything anything to solve your problem?

Comment: @apokryfos first of all why not TypeScript? and I tried the last answer but It didn't work

Comment: When it comes to runtime, TypeScript no longer applies because it gets compiled to JavaScript and this question is about code behaviour at runtime. Also, show us the code you've tried. You don't have to share actual data, sample data would be ok

Comment: @apokryfos ok, I changed the Tags, about the code, because that my data is coming from API call as the interface I added and not as a list of dates, I did'nt know what to write in the last solution  instead of 
```const activities = [
  { date: new Date('2019-06-28') },
  { date: new Date('2020-05-10') },
  { date: new Date('2021-01-22') }
]```

Comment: If you're getting data from the API then it's unlikely the date you're getting is a Date instance. It's more likely a string. If it's an ISO formatted string then you can do `const todaysActivities = activities.filter(a => a.issue_date >= '2021-06-01T00:00:00Z' && a.issue_date < '2021-06-02T00:00:00Z')` or if you want to get more sophisticated you can crate date instances in that callback and compare them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233219/discussion-between-ishay-and-apokryfos).

Comment: @apokryfos is this reasonable? ```return this.http.post<any>(this.URL, body).pipe(
      filter(a => a.issue_date >= yesterday && a.issue_date < today)
    );```

Comment: Update your question with actual code you're trying and sample data. Also tag your question correctly. That looks like an angular-style request so if you are using angular then tag it as such so people who know angular can actually answer or comment.

Comment: @apokryfos Did it, but someone wrote before that this isn't angular so I removed the tag

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution if the data is arranged in the order of the dates, it is to retrieve the data in the index tab [n-1] n being the size of the array

```
var data = tabArray[tabArray.length - 1];
```

Comment: Request was for data for last day not last record

Comment: @khassim First of all thank you for the answer, but like Alexander wrote I need the data from the last day and not the last record.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const activities = [
  { date: new Date('2019-06-28') },
  { date: new Date('2020-05-10') },
  { date: new Date('2021-01-22') }
]

const sortedA =  activities.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});

const sortedAct = activities.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date);
const sortedActs = activities.slice().sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date);

console.log("sortedA: ", sortedA);
console.log("sortedAct: ", sortedAct);
console.log("sortedActs: ", sortedActs);

//Pipe date format {{valueDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! again sorry for my question I'm kind of new here. Based on my interface that I added, your answer is still the same?

Comment: I get this error about the return row: ```The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.```

Comment: U welcome. In `getSale()` the method is `POST` ?, `"issue_date":"2021-05-01 to 2021-05-31"` is not very clear. Did you get data on the component?. For chart the best and easy one is [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/)

Comment: Yes I get the data, meanwhile I solve my question and I will upload my solution for review